# C# sql command timeout

Tags: entity-framework

I have an application that has an SQL command timeout 3 minute. What would be the impact if query finishes processing in 1 minute?

Answer (score 2):

You get the result of the query, because there won't be a timeout. A timeout happens because the query takes longer than the allowed time, 3 minutes in this case. Because the query finishes in 1 minute, there's no timeout and you get your result. A timeout is meant to ensure that an operation does not take longer than the maximum allowed time.

Answer (score 1):

> ... sql command timeout 3 minute. what would be the impact if query finishes processing in 1 minute.

None at all.

The timeout *only* comes into affect if the query takes *longer* than the timeout, at which point the query is killed off and the application gets an error.